# problem with linking gtests in catkin

Tags: ros, catkin, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm migrating my code to catkin. So far so good, but I've been stuck on that one for some time already.

I'm building a package with some unit tests (gtest), and I get linker errors. The weird thing is that I am using the same linking command as for my executables.

here is my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(bag_of_tricks)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp serializable)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES bag_of_tricks
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp serializable
  DEPENDS Boost rt OpenCV
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(bag_of_tricks
  src/high_res_timer.cpp
  src/image_region_iterator.cpp
  src/lockable.cpp

  include/bag_of_tricks/high_res_timer.h
  include/bag_of_tricks/image_region_iterator.h
  include/bag_of_tricks/bag_of_tricks.h
  include/bag_of_tricks/lockable.h
)

add_executable(bag_of_tricks_dummy src/bag_of_tricks_dummy.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bag_of_tricks_dummy bag_of_tricks ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} rt)
    
catkin_add_gtest(test_bag_of_tricks_hrt src/test_hrt.cpp)
if(TARGET test_bag_of_tricks_hrt)
  target_link_libraries(test_bag_of_tricks_hrt bag_of_tricks ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} rt)
endif()

catkin_add_gtest(test_bag_of_tricks_lockable src/test_lockable.cpp)
if(TARGET test_bag_of_tricks_lockable)
  target_link_libraries(test_bag_of_tricks_lockable bag_of_tricks ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} rt)
endif()
```

And these are the errors I get (with VERBOSE=1):

```
Linking CXX executable /data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/bag_of_tricks/test_bag_of_tricks_hrt
cd /data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/build/libraries/bag_of_tricks && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test_bag_of_tricks_hrt.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/local/bin/c++   -g    CMakeFiles/test_bag_of_tricks_hrt.dir/src/test_hrt.cpp.o  -o /data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/bag_of_tricks/test_bag_of_tricks_hrt -rdynamic -L/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/build/gtest ../../gtest/libgtest.so /data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so -lpthread -lboost_signals-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcpp_common.so /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librostime.so -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_thread-mt /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librosconsole.so -lboost_regex-mt -llog4cxx /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so /data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libserializable.so /data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libyaml_cpp.so -lboost_thread-mt -lrt -lpthread /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librosconsole.so -lboost_regex-mt -llog4cxx /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so -lrt -Wl,-rpath,/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/build/gtest:/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib:/opt/ros/hydro/lib 
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so: undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, log4cxx::Logger*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so: undefined reference to `ros::console::initialize()'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::~disable_interruption()'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libserializable.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::path::filename() const'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so: undefined reference to `ros::console::initializeLogLocation(ros::console::LogLocation*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::console::levels::Level)'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so: undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_current_thread_data()'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libserializable.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so: undefined reference to `ros::console::setLogLocationLevel(ros::console::LogLocation*, ros::console::levels::Level)'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libserializable.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::detail::rename(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so: undefined reference to `ros::console::g_initialized'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libserializable.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet()'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libserializable.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so: undefined reference to `ros::console::checkLogLocationEnabled(ros::console::LogLocation*)'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libbag_of_tricks.so: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::disable_interruption()'
/data/driving_repos/rdr_v2/devel/lib/libserializable.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::path::parent_path() const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

You can see in the linker command that all the libraries seem to be here (-lrt provides clock_gettime for instance, boost_thread and boost_filesystem are here as well, rosconsole is there ...)

Again, this is the same linking command as the bag_of_tricks_dummy executable, which calls some of the functions from my library.

I also tried with if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING) as I have seen in some packages, I have tried to remove the conditional part, I tried with gtest as a test_depend in package.xml, and I'm running out of ideas now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82761/problem-with-linking-gtests-in-catkin/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-24**:
First, you want to keep the check for CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING around all your testing stuff (not that it makes a difference but the case that it can be omitted might not be supported in the future).

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-24**:
Have you tried to add the target link libraries to you library target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As pointed by Dirk Thomas, the solution was to target link my libraries with the required libraries, and do that in all packages depended upon.

---

Originally posted by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) with karma: 1001 on 2013-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2